# Test class code Coverage

Tags: trigger, unit-test

Can any one please help me with the below trigger to get the code coverage.

**Trigger:**

```
Trigger TaskEmailNotification  on Task (before update ) {
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Task tsk: Trigger.New){
        if(tsk.Status=='Completed' && Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById){
            ownerIds.add(tsk.CreatedById);      
        }        
    }

    // Build a map of all users who are assigned the tasks
    Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>([select Name, Email from User where Id in :ownerIds]);
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailMsglist=new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for(Task tsk : Trigger.New) {
        if(tsk.Status=='Completed' && Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById) {
           if(tsk.Owner.Profile.name!= 'GEAC Sales') {  
            User theUser = userMap.get(tsk.CreatedById);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {theUser.Email};

            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);    // Set the TO addresses 
            mail.setSubject('A Task has been updated');   // Set the subject 
            // Next, create a string template. Specify {0}, {1} etc. in place of actual values.
            String template = 'Hello {0}, \n\n Your Task has been Completed. Here are the details - \n\n';
            //  template+= 'taskid -'+tsk.id+' \n';
            template+= 'Subject: '+tsk.Subject+' \n';
            template+= 'Status: '+tsk.Status +' \n';
            template+= 'Priority: '+tsk.Priority +' \n';
            template+= '\n\nFor more details, click the following link: \n\n';
            template+= URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + tsk.Id;   

            List<String> args = new List<String>();     
            args.add(theUser.Name);
            // Here's the String.format()
            String formattedHtml = String.format(template, args);
            mail.setPlainTextBody(formattedHtml);
            emailMsglist.add(mail);  
           }   
        }     
    }
    Messaging.SendEmail(emailMsglist);
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData = true)
Public class TaskEmailNotificationTest
{
   Static testMethod void Test()
   {    
       Profile pf = [Select Id from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator'];
       Test.startTest();
       User u = new User();
                //u.FirstName = 'Test';
                u.LastName = 'Nicomatic2';
                u.Email = 'test@gmail.com.sandbox';
                u.CompanyName = 'test.com';
                u.Title = 'Test User';
                u.Username = 'test@gmail.com.sandbox';
                u.Alias = 'ni';
                u.CommunityNickname = 'ni';
                u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Mexico_City';
                u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
                u.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
                u.ProfileId = pf.Id;
                u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';       
                insert u;
        User u1 = new User();
                //u.FirstName = 'Test';
                u1.LastName = 'Nicomatic22';
                u1.Email = 'test1@gmail.com.sandbox';
                u1.CompanyName = 'tes1t.com';
                u1.Title = 'Test User1';
                u1.Username = 'test1@gmail.com.sandbox';
                u1.Alias = 'ni1';
                u1.CommunityNickname = 'ni1';
                u1.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Mexico_City';
                u1.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
                u1.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
                u1.ProfileId = pf.Id;
                u1.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';       
                insert u1; 
       EmailTemplate template = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'SupportSelfServiceNewLoginandPassword'];            
       Task task= new task();
       task.Subject='Message Sent';
       task.status='In Progress';   
       //task.OwnerId = user1.Id; 
       insert task;
       task.status='Completed';
       update task;
       Test.stopTest();                      
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: Hi,  Test class code coverage  is showing as 34%   Below lines are not covered     if(tsk.Status=='Completed' && Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById){
            ownerIds.add(tsk.CreatedById);

Comment: how much was the code coverage when you had not commented out this line ?    task.OwnerId = user1.Id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition is failing at `tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById`.  So, the code below this line is not covered.  You need to set the ownerId for the task as some user in your test class.

```
task.OwnerId = user1.Id;
```

Also use,

```
System.runAs(user2){
    insert task;
}
```

This way, the owner and createdById will be different for the task and it will cover the whole code.

Comment: Hi, Still am facing same problem please find my Edit code and let me know if any i missed out

Comment: you haven't used the System.runAs(user2) in your code

Comment: Ya you are rgt...Now code coverage is showing 100%...Thank you.

Comment: Hey...I have One more doubt in the same trigger that is we need to restrict the email notifications to  created by the Specific roles/profiles .Can you please help me on this

Comment: That's for a different question.  You can mark this answer as the solution/accepted and create new one.  Anyways, you can use like this if(user.Profile.Name=='xxxxx') { ...do action....}

Answer (score 0):

You will try this code .u get 100% code coverage on that trigger.

```
    @isTest(SeeAllData=true)public class TaskEmailNotificationTest{  static testMethod void Test(){    
Test.startTest();
Account oacc = new Account(Name = 'Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory');
Profile p = [SELECT id, name FROM profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
User u = new User(alias = 's2471e3s', email='amitstandarduser1@testorg.coms24714e3',emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Test1', languagelocalekey='en_US',localesidkey='en_US', timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='amitstandarduser@testorg.coms24714e3', Firstname = 'Test', profileid = p.Id);
insert u; 
User u1 = new User(alias = 's2471e3', email='amitsta1ndarduser1@testorg.coms24714e3',emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Test1', languagelocalekey='en_US',localesidkey='en_US', timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='amitstandarduser1@testorg.coms24714e3', Firstname = 'Test1', profileid = p.Id);
insert u1; 
EmailTemplate template = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'SupportSelfServiceNewLoginandPassword'];            
Task task= new task();
task.Subject='Message Sent';
task.status='In Progress';   
task.OwnerId = u.id;  
System.runAs(u1){
  insert task;
}
task.status='Completed';
update task;
Test.stopTest();
```

}
}

Comment: Hi Rajesh,   Thank you....i got 100% code coverage now...I have one more doubt have you any idea to need to restrict the email notifications to only those tasks created by the Specific roles/profiles .